# i am trying to do simple animate function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

i am trying to animate a **div**, what i need is when **click a button** i want to hide a div and show another div that is next child.

here is my [`fiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/7UCdS/2/).

I am trying to do like this [this site](http://www.eharmony.com/) here you can see when you click the **learmore** link which is in the top-right hand side then another div content open like sliding.

Comment: lol you *really* need to clean up the formatting in the question.

Comment: yup you need to show code in presentable form so that others can understand.anyways,did you get any error in error console.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DEMO jsBin](http://jsbin.com/uqemay/edit#javascript,html,live)**

```
var c=0;
$('.slide:gt(0)').hide();
$('#learn').click(function(){
  c++;
  $('.slide').eq(c).css({zIndex:c}).show('slow');
});
```

HTML:

```
  <div id="slider">
    <div id="learn">Learn more</div>
    <div class="slide s1">I'm slide 1</div>
    <div class="slide s2">I'm slide 2</div>
    <div class="slide s3">I'm slide 3</div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
  #slider{
    position:relative;
    width:340px;
    height:340px;
  }
  #learn{
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    z-index:2;          /*set a higher Z-index if you have more slides*/
    cursor:pointer;
  }
  .slide{
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;         /*important!! To 'slide' from right to left*/
    top:0px;           
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
  }
```

If you have a defined number of slides you can keep the code intact, in the other hand I'd suggest you to - when the last slide is reached - hide the #learn programatically with jQuery. Let me know if you need help with that one.

Happy coding

Comment: hi this is too good, you answered exactly what i want, thank you so much :) :)

Comment: @Suresh - (I undoed some changes I made.) Thanks!

Comment: hi i added one more div but it's not working here is link http://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/faE5Q/2/

Comment: You need to set the zindex for the #learn dim acording to the number of slides, ie. set z-index:3; for four slides.

Answer (score 0):

Will something like this suffice:

```
$('#divtohide').fadeOut('slow', function() {
  $('#divtoshow').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

You can change the ids as needed.

**EDIT**

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MR5yv/1/

**EDIT #2**

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MR5yv/2/

Comment: that i know i trying to do like this site http://www.eharmony.com/ here in the top-right side you can see a link learnmore when you click that the present div slide-down slowly and next div will appear like slide-down

Comment: i am unable to find the learn more link on the site you mentioned.

Comment: Please check out the fiddle in my updated answer. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: what you did is good, but what i want is slidedown a active div content from top-right side to left-bottom side(that means hiding the div content) and the same time slide down next div content from top-right side to left-bottom side(that means displaying the next div content) please help me to complete this